# list directory entries in the svn repository

Tags: linux, ubuntu, svn, solaris, repository

please every body  help me .... i am going to explain my problem and i hope if anyone know the answer support me by it.
i want to konw the list directory entries in the svn repository ...i konw "list" command give me the result but i have many many repository ...so this is unlogical method .... so i need method to find the entries directory for more than one svn repository at the same time

Comment: Would it be possible to provide some example data? I think you might get better answers if you could provide a couple of example repository structures and the expected output you'd want from traversing them.

Comment: ok ... see the following example.... i do the following :- execute the this command to find the repository :- "sudo find / -type f -name fs-type -print " the following result appear :- "/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/impl/VJ/resources /var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/impl/JKB/code/iris" and more maybe 500 repository now i want to show content of each repository for Followed in the next comment >>

Comment: now i want to find the content of each repository for example :-"/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/core" so i execute this command :- "svn list svn+ssh://svn.sts.com.jo/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/core" but i have maybe 500 repository it is very complex to execute it for each one ...Taking into account each one require password

Comment: note :- someone Suggest to me to write bash

Comment: Do _not_ go around asking the same question over and over again: http://serverfault.com/questions/181712/how-i-can-list-directory-entries-in-the-repository-i-have-a-large-number-of-re and http://serverfault.com/questions/181744/how-i-can-write-patch-file-to-list-directory-entries-in-the-svn-repository

Comment: answer me please if you know ... if you don't know go to another page :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVN by itself doesn't have any concept of passwords, it's only when you reference an SVN repository through something like Apache (mod_authz) that you are prompted for a username and password.  So if you can execute the sudo command then you can also execute this command

```
svn list --recursive file:///var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/core
```