# repository and its content?

Tags: linux, svn, ubuntu, solaris, repository

how i can view svn repository and its directory .... i have large number of svn repository

Comment: possible duplicate of [list directory entries in the svn repository](http://serverfault.com/questions/182547/list-directory-entries-in-the-svn-repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a Windows client (XP, Vista, 7), you can use the free [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) tool to connect to any remote SVN server.

When connected, you can browse the folder tree of a repository with Tortoise SVN.